# How to implement the circle wheel effect on Android 4.2?

Tags: android, rotation, imageview, android-custom-view, image-rotation

As the following effect pictures, how to implement the effect ?

[image]

**Note:**

1. User can rotate the circle to select the desired value
2. The value(100,200,...3200) pointing by the arrow should **match** the value which on the circle background

I can rotate the circle ,using the **mMatrix.postRotate(...)** and **setImageMatrix(mMatrix)** at present. However, I cannot find a proper way to match the desired and right value on the circle.

I searched the related question and cost too much time about it , but I still have no idea about the mismatching problem.

The effect is same as the [chordwheel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.pe.elex.chordwheel) .

**Related link:**

(1)[rotate dial in limited degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067633/rotate-dial-in-limited-degrees?rq=1)

(2)[Draw text in circular view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150642/draw-text-in-circular-view)

(3)[Rotate Images Around a Circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826982/rotate-images-around-a-circle)

(4)[Radial menu android with button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577200/radial-menu-android-with-button-click)